# Access this in firebase.Promise<any> then

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, promise

[I added an Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGIsL.png) I am not able to see the this variable in the then method of the firebase.Promise. I also can not see _this.

```
this._messaging.getToken().then( (currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    console.log('Ok!!!!!');
  //  _notificationToken = currentToken;
  } else {
    console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
  }
})
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  });
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you give more detail? What's expected to happen? What is actually happening?

Comment: I managed to solve it by having a "const that = this; " before the call. Now I have the problem that in the onMessage function I can not access the "this" variable. I created a git repository to simulate the problem , can you please take a look https://gitlab.com/bratualex/angular-firebase

Comment: Add in the added information to the Question itself, not as a comment. So that other can better view your question and answer it.

Comment: Where is your `onMessage` function?

Comment: I added an Image with the error after I the change you proposed. there is something in the this variable but not what I expect.